# How to fix the "unrecognized option --run" on NetBeans running PHPUnit

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit

I'm trying to run the PHPUnit into the NetBeans 8.0.2.

If I run # phpunit inside my folder tests all tests run. So it's seems been set right.

But in the NetBeans output I always got:

```
"C:\nginx\php\5.6.12\php.exe" "C:\nginx\php\5.6.12\phpunit.phar" "--colors" "--log-junit" "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\nb-phpunit-log.xml" "--bootstrap" "E:\var\www\...\tests\TestHelper.php" "--configuration" "E:\var\www\...\tests\phpunit.xml" "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php" "--run=E:\var\www\...\tests\app\utils\FormatUtilTest.php"
```

PHPUnit 4.8.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

unrecognized option --run

Done.

Maybe the "--run message" it's right, because this command doesn't exist in the PHPUnit manual. But if is that so, how to create another script for the NetBeans execute the tests?

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue yesterday after a PHPUnit update. So I reverted back to PHPUnit 4.7.7 for now, until this is fixed in NB.

Answer (score 3):

I too have encountered this error causing the latest version of PHPUnit not to work with NetBeans v8.0.2.

Further investigating this issue has resulted in determining that there is an incompatibility between NetBeansSuite.php and the latest version of PHPUnit.

The error 'unrecognized option --run' is being thrown by the phpunit.phar and not being thrown by NetBeansSuite.php. I also do not believe the NetBeansSuite.php is even being executed.

phpunit.phar, line 63816 *or* 63894, is where the exception is being thrown.

Until this is fixed, PHPUnit will not work from NetBeans v8.0.2.

@Pablo: I thank you for opening an issue and have commented on your issue.

PHPUnit v4.7.7 works correctly.

Opened a bug report: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=254276

Comment: Bug is now fixed in NB Nightly.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is: [This was indeed a bug in NB and is now fixed in nightly](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=254276).

Possible solutions:

- Upgrade to latest nightly from http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/nightly/
- Use PHPUnit 4.7.7 as mentioned by Luuk

Answer (score 1):

"--run" option is used in the NetBeansSuite.php for running tests. So, you should submit that to NetBeans bugzilla [1] if you want to avoid that.

[1] https://netbeans.org/community/issues.html (PHP/PHPUnit)

Answer (score 0):

2019 and the problem still exists. Downgrading PHPUnit is no option anymore today. So I created, as a workaround, a wrapper script for phpunit which takes care of removing the bad parameters.

It also removes the NetBeansSuite.php file completely because it does the same a call directly to the phpunit script would.

My setup is Windows Netbeans 11, Windows PHP 7.3, and a cygwin wrapper (because it's bash code). If somebody feels like porting this to native windows, please leave a comment here.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# modified phpunit script originally from vendors dir
# 1. cygwin default search path is bad in my installation...
PATH="$PATH:/bin:/usr/bin"
# original code, only adjust the ../../ to match your installation.
# the directory this is run in is where the wrapper script resides
dir=$(cd "${0%[/\\]*}" > /dev/null; cd "../../vendor/phpunit/phpunit" && pwd)
if [ -d /proc/cygdrive ] && [[ $(which php) == $(readlink -n /proc/cygdrive)/* ]]; then
   # We are in Cgywin using Windows php, so the path must be translated
   dir=$(cygpath -m "$dir");
fi
# fix netbeans parameters
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
  case "$1" in
    *NetBeansSuite.php) shift;;
    --run=*) PARAMS="$PARAMS ${1#--run=}"; shift;;
    --) shift ;;
    *) PARAMS="$PARAMS $1"; shift;;
  esac
done

"${dir}/phpunit" $PARAMS
```

You have to adjust both occurrences of "../"s to your folder structure.

This solution works with ALT-F6 (run all tests), right clicking a test folder "Run Tests" and also single test files right click "Run".

The setting for "Netbeans: Tools/Options/Frameworks & Tools/PHPUnit" is then:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe /cygdrive/c/workspace/Project/src/cli/phpunit
```

Adjust these path names to your needs, again.

HTH,

M.